# Flutter/Dart Make Missing Item in JSON Listview Automatically Anonymous?

Tags: mysql, json, flutter, class

I've got a Listview in Flutter which grabs JSON items from a MySQL database . Each item in the list contains a userid, username and avatar. Occasionally the user had been deleted so the database returns "NULL" for each column. How can I automatically assign "userid" to "1", "username" to "anonymous" and avatar to "anonymous.jpg"?

Here's the class I'm using for the listview;

```
class AccountContent {
  String? name;
  String? avatar;
  String? userid;
      
  AccountContent({this.name, this.avatar, this.userid});

  AccountContent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    avatar = "https://mysite/avatar.jpg";
    userid = json['userid'];    
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['avatar'] = this.avatar;
    data['userid'] = this.userid;    
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `default null check operator (??)` to assign default value when the field is null.

```
class AccountContent {
  String? name;
  String? avatar;
  String? userid;
     
  AccountContent({this.name, this.avatar, this.userid});

  AccountContent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'] ?? "1";
    avatar = "https://mysite/avatar.jpg" ?? "anonymous.jpg";
    userid = json['userid'] ?? "anonymous";    
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['avatar'] = this.avatar;
    data['userid'] = this.userid;    
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Good idea! However I'm getting an error when I use a URL.  For example:  avatar = "mysite.com" + json['gavatar'] ?? "mysite.com" +  anonymous.jpg;  Heres' the error; Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.

Comment: Can you provide the json which is came from api (mysql) so that I can understand the json structure according to your code.

Comment: Here's the Mysql query; SELECT 
    ap.userid, 
    u.gavatar,  
    u.name, 
 FROM 
    audioposts ap       
 LEFT JOIN 
    accounts u ON u.id = ap.userid 
    LEFT JOIN
    entitytag et ON et.audioid = ap.audioid
    WHERE ap.opid = "0"`;

Comment: The only workaround I can see at the moment is if I put the URL in the mysql database. Makes it a pain if I ever change sites though...

Comment: Thats also a good idea